# PHP - How can I retain values of textbox array after form submit?

Tags: php, forms

I just have a question.

I have a group of textbox with the same name. (name = "quantity[]")

How can I retain the values of the form after submit? For example, I have 5 textbox with the same name. I filled out 4 of them and submitted the form. I want to display an error that a field is empty and retain the values that I put before I submitted the form.

I can do it if the textbox names are different. But if they have the same, I can't make it work.

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['quantity'])) echo $_POST['quantity'];?>">

<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['quantity'])) echo $_POST['quantity'];?>">

<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['quantity'])) echo $_POST['quantity'];?>">

<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['quantity'])) echo $_POST['quantity'];?>">

<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Thanks for your help php people. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['quantity'][0])) echo $_POST['quantity'][0]` - ..[1] for the second and so on

Comment: Try using JS for validation and AJAX to submit the form so that you can retain your data if the submit fails

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for you quick answer. What if my textboxes are dynamically created, it could be 2 or 10, it depends how many items the user will select. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @hungrykoala, Hi, hungry koala, I can do it in ajax jquery, but I want to know if how to do this in PHP. Thankyou so much.

Comment: How will you determine the number of textboxes?

Comment: @hungrykoala hello. I have a table (#item-list-table) with a list of items.The user will select items from that table. Whatever they selected in that table, will be transferred to another table (#selected-items). I used jQuery to do that. So if they selected 10 items from #item-list-table, I will have 10 textboxes on my #selected-items table. Each item row has a quantity field on it. Thanks hungrykoala. I hope I explained it well. I am not really good in English.

Comment: Use samuels answer but remove the else since that won't make it dynamic.

Comment: @hungrykoala, Wow it works! Thanks man. Samuels answer suddenly clicked on my head. I now understand how it works. Thank you for helping, hungrykoala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If field quantity is not fixed, that is, it varies. You should use for loop  like this

```
     <?php

        if(!empty($_POST['quantiy'])){

        $count =count($_POST['quantity']);

        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

        ?>
        <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['quantity'][$i];?>">

        <?php

               }
            } 
    else
    {

    ?>

    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="">

<?php
    }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you loose the reference to the input fields when the form is submitted. Since all fields have the same name you cannot be sure, which one provided the input.

What you can do: You could populate your form fields by popping the $_POST like so:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['quantity'])) echo array_pop($_POST['quantity']);?>">
```

What happens is the following:

- upon submission your $_POST-variable gets populated depending on which inputs have any values
- after submission at re-rendering the $_POST['quantities'] array gets disassembled, the last element gets removed and it populates the form input

A word of caution: If the user fills out field 1,2 and 4 with this code the fields 1,2 and 3 will be populated.